# InterlockedIncrement vs EnterCriticalSection/counter++/LeaveCriticalSection

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, thread-safety

I have some multithreaded code (see question [Windows API Thread Pool simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357955/windows-api-thread-pool-simple-example) ) for which I am using a counter to identify a thread.

I have been advised to use an InterlockedIncrement to increment this counter in the thread's callback function. However this didn't seem to properly lock the variable, as I encountered some concurrency issues. I replaced the InterlockedIncrement by using a critical section manually : EnterCriticalSection/counter++/LeaveCriticalSection and this now works perfectly.

Why is it so ? Aren't the two options supposed to be strictly equivalent ?
Note that I am talking about launching just a couple (about 10) of threads.

Comment: In what way didn't it seem to properly lock the variable? What concurrency issues did you encounter?

Comment: `InterlockedIncrement` and friends don't need to lock.  The perform single assembly instructions.  Can you be more descriptive about the problems you were seeing?

Comment: LukeH : the counter didn't always give a strictly increasing consecutive sequence of integers. Sometimes the counter, starting from 0, was doing : 0 1 2 2 4 5...

Comment: @WhitAngl: How are you checking the counter's value?

Comment: LukeH: first I realized that the thread IDs were wrong because the final result of my calculations were (sometimes) wrong. For the specific value of the counter, I just write a number in a table indexed by the counter's value. Some entries in the table are not written while others are written twice, although each entry in the table should be written only once. Actually, running the code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357955/windows-api-thread-pool-simple-example thousands of time should reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your code is not using `InterlockedIncrement` correctly.

```
InterlockedIncrement(&(thread.threadCount)); 
DWORD tid = (thread.threadCount-1)%thread.size();
```

This performs an atomic increment of `thread.threadCount`, but instead of saving the atomically-incremented value, you ignore it and go back to the `thread.threadCount` variable (which may have been incremented by another thread in the meantime).

In your case, what happens is that two threads did an `InterlockedIncrement` nearly simultaneously, incrementing it from 1 to 2, then 2 to 3. Both threads then read `thread.threadCount` and got 3 back (then subtracted 1 to get a final result of 2).

The correct code is

```
LONG tidUnique = InterlockedIncrement(&(thread.threadCount));
DWORD tid = (tidUnique-1)%thread.size();
```

The unique incremented value is returned by `InterlockedIncrement`. You need to use that value in your computations if you want to see the unique value.